# How to automatically set author on new issues in SonarQube with TFS

Tags: tfs, sonarqube

According to [Automatic Issue Assignment](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Automatic+Issue+Assignment) all issues will be assigned to the committer. But when I'm looking at the issues overview page on our SonarQube portal I can't see any author/assignee.
Am I missing some configuration?

We are using TFS for our Source Control.
The names on TFS are the same on SonarQube.
I've added domain names as SCM accounts.

Comment: Did all developers login at least one to the SonarQube server? SCM can assign issues only when users are available in a SonarQube database. If you use LDAP, then all people have to login - their accounts will be automaticaly created.

Comment: Every developer has logged in and has an account in SonarQube. I'm not sure if the accounts were automatically created

Answer (score 1):

As far I'm aware Automatic Issue Assign is a SCM dependent feature. Please ensure you have the correct SCM plugin installed within SonarQube.

- For TFVC: https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-scm-tfvc/ (No longer maintained and is targeted for SonarQube 5.0, compatibility with current LTS and/or Latest is uncertain)
- For GIT: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Git+Plugin

Comment: I've tried the sonar-scm-tfvc plugin, but we're running SonarQube on a Linux machine

Comment: Personally I've only used GIT on TFS, so I'm not aware of which constraints TFVC has on the used OS.